# Run-time error '5' Invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: vba, excel

I have a horrible problem with this part of the code ... I've checked everywhere and looked for many options but nothing seems to work... would anyone know why do I keep receiving error here? I am following one of the video courses and even though the code looks exactly the same (except for source data part) I still get it... appreciate any hint on this...
I get this run time error on setting object variable "pt"

```
Sub CreatePivotTableandPivotCache()

Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable


Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=Sheet1.Name & "!" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address, _
    Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

Worksheets.Add
Range("A3").Select

Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable( _
    TableDestination:=ActiveCell, _
    TableName:="KPI")

End Sub
```

Comment: It's a name for pivot table I would like to create

Comment: I think @peakpeak means what is the active cell?

Comment: Sorry. I start anew. I got it working but only if there are data in Sheet1!A1, A2 and so on

Comment: Worksheets.Add
Range("A3").Select

A3 in new worksheet

Comment: Well his original code works with values 1 in A1 and 2 in A2 in Sheet1. The new worksheet is only the destination for the pivot table and initially contains no data

Comment: Why is `Sheet1` referred to with its code name (`Sheet1`), and then *in the same instruction* dereferenced from the `Worksheets` collection off whatever workbook is currently active (unqualified `Worksheets` implicitly refers to `ActiveWorkbook`)? `SourceData:=Sheet1.Name & "!" & Sheet1.Range("A1")...`